# Python opencv cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS

Tags: python, opencv

Based on the `cv2.kmeans` function, I have written a function "F(Image)" with "label" as output.

```
ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(Image,K,None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
```

The output of F(Image), "label", is later used for other image processing.

However, I need to run F(Image) for numerous images. I noticed that the labels are different if I ran, say, F(Image1) and F(Image2) consecutively versus F(Image1) and F(Image2) separately.

My suspicion is that every time `cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS` is ran, it starts at a different random number.

Without going into the source code of `cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS`, is there any way to ensure that the labels are the same every time I run the code? Or run F(Image1) and F(Image2) as in they are ran separately.

Comment: Don't know in the Python wrapper, but in C++ using `cv::theRNG().state = myseed;` before each call to `kmeans` should work

Answer (score 2):

[`cv2.kmeans()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_kmeans/py_kmeans_opencv/py_kmeans_opencv.html) takes 2 type of flags: `cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS` and `cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS`.

### `cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS:`

With this flag enabled, the method always starts with a random set of initial samples, and tries to converge from there depending upon your `TermCirteria`.

#### Pros:

- Saves computation Time.

#### Cons:

- Doesn't guarantee same labels for the exact same image.

### `cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS:`

With this flag enabled, the method first iterates the whole image to determine the probable centers and then starts to converge.

#### Pros:

- Would yield optimum and consistent results for same input image

#### Cons:

- Takes extra computation time for iterating all the pixels and determining probable samples.

**Note:** I have also read about another flag `cv::KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS`, using which you can pass custom samples, which are used by the method to converge, But in the documentation linked, that flag is not mentioned, Not Sure if it has been deprecated or the documentation is not updated.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS. It is frustrating. I scaled my images by 2 and 1/2 times. While the segmentation is nice, the labels are different for each scale.

I think it comes down to the questions. How do you ensure that k-means will give the same label every time? Now sure if there is a way to do that :(

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224759/how-to-avoid-k-means-assigning-different-labels-on-different-run

Comment: Down-scaling the image causes interpolation between the pixel values, or in worse case, some pixels may vanish as well. In the question you haven't mentioned the down scaling of input image.Also K-means is an un-supervised algorithm So results may vary slightly, I guess you should compare the results, taking into account some epsilon value,

Answer (score 1):

The method only keeps the best labels after each iteration. So if the number of iterations you set is high enough, let's say `cv2.kmeans(Image,K,None,criteria,100,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)`, the output result would be similar.